# Is it possible to change the minimumTrackTintColor of a slider dynamically as the user moves it forward and backwards?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

So here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var volumeSliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBAction func volumeSliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {

    player.volume = volumeSliderOutlet.value / 255

    let green = Float(255 / volumeSliderOutlet.value)

    volumeSliderOutlet.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255.0, green: green, blue: 25.0, alpha: 1.0)

    print(green)

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to change the minimumTrackTintColor of the volumeSliderOutlet as the user moves it. This code turns the minimumTrackTintColor white as soon as I touch the slider circle. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Damn, rmaddy, the question you're referring to is 5 years old, they are not talking about the same Swift version, are they? I've got a particular issue and I'm looking for a particular answer.

Comment: The age is irrelevant. You need to pass color component values in the range 0.0 - 1.0, not 0 to 255.

Comment: Now that's helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I simply stated what the duplicate question and its answers are telling you.

Comment: "You need to pass color component values in the range 0.0 - 1.0, not 0 to 255." This is concise and what I was looking for. Gracias!